# How can I evaluate pre-defined symbolic variables array in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, eval, sympy, code-conversion

I have a MATLAB code and I'm trying to convert it to Python. I used the eval() to evaluate my symbolic arrays in MATLAB. But I couldn't find how to solve this in Python. Here's a simple example:

MATLAB Code:

```matlab
%values to be assigned
input = [10 20 30; ...
         15 25 20; ...
         20 20 10]

%decision variables     
x_1_1 = input(1)    
x_2_1 = input(2)    
x_3_1 = input(3)    
x_1_2 = input(4)
x_2_2 = input(5)    
x_3_2 = input(6)
x_1_3 = input(7)    
x_2_3 = input(8)    
x_3_3 = input(9)

%symbolic arrray
symbolic_eq  = sym('x_',[3,3])

%any math operation    
m  =  [-1  0  0 ; ...
        0 -1  0 ; ...
        0  1 -1 ]

% new equations for symbolic array    
multp_eq  = m*symbolic_eq

% get results
results   = eval(multp_eq)
```

Python code:

```python
from sympy import *
import numpy as np

#values to be assigned
input = np.array([[10, 20, 30, 15, 25, 20, 20, 20, 10]])

#decision variables
x_1_1 = input[0]
x_2_1 = input[1]
x_3_1 = input[2]
x_1_2 = input[3]
x_2_2 = input[4]
x_3_2 = input[5]
x_1_3 = input[6]
x_2_3 = input[7]
x_3_3 = input[8]

#symbolic array (edited)
symbolic_eq = symarray('x', (4, 4))
symbolic_eq = np.array(symbolic_eq [1:, 1:])

#any math operation
m  =  np.array([[-1,  0,  0 ],
                [ 0, -1,  0 ],
                [ 0,  1, -1 ]])

#new equations for symbolic array
multp_eq  = m*symbolic_eq

# get results
results   = eval(multp_eq)
```

Also, for both MATLAB and Python, how can I define my input() variables easily?

Comment: First index of symarray is 0 not 1.

Comment: I revised the python symarray function code. I had considered this situation in my code but forgot it here. thanks @Corralien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code was you needed to do the substitution (with the method `.subs()` before you could evaluate your expression. This is done by providing a list tuples containing the variable and its value. Here I build this list in a for loop.

A few extra comments about your code. In general, avoid the commands like `from sympy import *` . It fills your namespace for no good reason. Finally, I see no "good" reasons to go to indices starting from 1 rather than 0. I suggest to consider switching to the native indexing, as it often makes the code cleaner.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np

#values to be assigned
aninput = np.array([[10, 20, 30],
                    [15, 25, 20],
                    [20, 20, 10]])

#symbolic array (edited)
symbolic_eq = sp.symarray('x', (4, 4))
symbolic_eq = symbolic_eq [1:, 1:]

thesubs = []
for index, theinput in np.ndenumerate(aninput):
    thesubs.append((symbolic_eq[index], aninput[index]))
print(thesubs)

#any math operation
m  =  sp.Matrix([[-1,  0,  0 ],
                [ 0, -1,  0 ],
                [ 0,  1, -1 ]])

#new equations for symbolic array
multp_eq  = m*symbolic_eq

# get results
results   = multp_eq.subs(thesubs)
results
```

Finally, this code will not run very fast. If you want to do this operation for a large number of input array of values, you should consider using `sympy.lambdify` instead of `.subs`.

```
function = sp.lambdify(np.array(symbolic_eq).flatten(), multp_eq, modules="numpy" )
```

Then you just have to call the function to get the answer:

```
result = function(*aninput.flatten())
```

On my machine, and for this simple example, this last line is **almost 400 times faster** than the one using subs. However, if the size of your imput array can increase, then this solution can run into some limitations (to 256 values if I remember).

Comment: Very useful functions @Romain Laugier. While the second is more efficient, there will be places where I'll use the first as well. I will consider your advice about import* and native indexing.